# get Maven project.artifactId from groovy script

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven

Here is one more question...

I'm trying to get maven project.artifactId from within groovy script. That's seems to be not so easy, though. Here is the code I use:

```
String getArtifactName() {
    String artifactName = project.properties.getProperty('project.artifactId')
    if (artifactName == null || artifactName == "") {
        println artifactName
        println "[ERROR] Unable to parse artifact path."
        println "[ERROR] Artifact won't be uploaded on the target server."
    } else {
        println artifactName
        return artifactName
    }
}
```

It ends up with error and with `artifactName==null`. However, if I define some user defined property, say `user`, it is parsed wonderfully.

Is there my mistakes or it is a restriction of maven/gmaven/groovy?

Thanks in advance for you help!

p.s. Any workarounds are acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to gmaven mail list I was able to resolve this. It seems that built-in maven variables/properties are not accessable through the `project.properties.getProperty()` funciton. To get such a properties from the project we need to use just `project.artifactId` for maven `artifactId` variable